# Determinant by using Gauss-elimination method, C++

Tags: c++

I have to find determinant of order n using Gauss elimination method.
I wrote this code:

```
// Determinant gauss decomposition
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    //Taking input from user
    int m, dim;
    cout << " Please enter the dimension of determinant and the coefficients" << endl;
    cin >> dim;
    cout << "Dimension =" << dim << endl;
    float n, det = 1.0, given[dim][dim], trans[dim][dim], temp[1][dim];
    // "given" is for given matrix and "trans" is for transformed matrix
    // "temp" is temporary matrix used for storing a row temporarily

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            cout << "   a" << i << j << " =  ";
            cin >> given[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl
         << "The input matrix is:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        cout << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            cout << given[i][j] << "   ";
    }

    // first transformation
    // srow is the row which has to be subtracted.
    for (int srow = 0; srow < dim; srow++) {
        if (srow < dim - 1) {
            cout << endl
                 << " after " << srow + 1 << " transformation: the transformed elements are " << endl;
            // This shows matrix after each transformation.
        }
        for (int row = 1; row < dim - srow; row++) {
            cout << endl;
            for (int col = 0; col < dim; col++) {
                if (given[srow][srow] != 0) //new
                {
                    trans[row + srow][col] = given[srow + row][col] - given[srow][col] * (given[row + srow][srow] / given[srow][srow]);
                }
                else {
                    cout << "  after changing row, ";
                    for (int col = 0; col < dim; col++) {
                        temp[1][col] = given[srow][col];

                        given[srow][col] = -1 * given[srow + 1][col];
                        given[srow + 1][col] = temp[1][col];
                        cout << "         given[" << srow << "][" << col << "] =    "
                             << given[srow][col];
                    }
                    goto fmat;
                }
            }
        }
        // showing the transformed elements after each transformation
        for (int p = 1; p < dim - srow; p++) {
            for (int q = 0; q < dim; q++) {
                given[p + srow][q] = trans[p + srow][q];
                cout << "         given[" << p + srow << "][" << q << "] = " << given[p + srow][q];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        // After each transformation, the transformed matrix is taken as the
        //given matrix.
        if (srow < dim - 1) {
            cout << endl
                 << " after " << srow + 1 << " transformation, the given matrix transforms to   " << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int p = 0; p < dim; p++) {
            for (int q = 0; q < dim; q++) {
                cout << "           given[" << p << "][" << q << "] = " << given[p][q];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

// Final transformed upper triangular matrix
fmat:
    cout << endl
         << " The final transformed matrix : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            cout << given[i][j] << "        ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // determinant calculation
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        det = det * given[i][i];
    }
    cout << "determinant = " << det;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I got:

```
 Please enter the dimension of determinant and the coefficients
3
Dimension =3
 a00 =  1
 a01 =  2
 a02 =  3
 a10 =  2
 a11 =  3
 a12 =  1
 a20 =  3
 a21 =  1
 a22 =  2

The input matrix is:

1   2   3
2   3   1
3   1   2
after 1 transformation: the transformed elements are


     given[1][0] = 0         given[1][1] = -1         given[1][2] = -5
     given[2][0] = 0         given[2][1] = -5         given[2][2] = -7

after 1 transformation, the given matrix transforms to

       given[0][0] = 1           given[0][1] = 2          given[0][2] = 3
       given[1][0] = 0           given[1][1] = -1         given[1][2] = -5
       given[2][0] = 0           given[2][1] = -5         given[2][2] = -7

after 2 transformation: the transformed elements are

     given[2][0] = 0              given[2][1] = 0         given[2][2] = 18

after 2 transformation, the given matrix transforms to

       given[0][0] = 1           given[0][1] = 2          given[0][2] = 3
       given[1][0] = 0           given[1][1] = -1         given[1][2] = -5
       given[2][0] = 0           given[2][1] = 0          given[2][2] = 18

       given[0][0] = 1           given[0][1] = 2          given[0][2] = 3
       given[1][0] = 0           given[1][1] = -1         given[1][2] = -5
       given[2][0] = 0           given[2][1] = 0          given[2][2] = 18

 The final transformed matrix :

 1        2        3
 0        -1        -5
 0        0        18
 determinant = -18
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 13.801 s
```

Press any key to continue.

The problem is: I am getting the transformed matrix twice after 2nd transformation in the output.
Can you please help me to improve the code so that it shows the concerned transformed matrix only once?

Comment: This question would not be useful again to anyone else, so won't answer it. But you need to move the `}` above, before the `for`.

Comment: Please format your code. It's not readable. You can use http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: Please be aware that code like `given[dim][dim]` is [not valid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).